# Any cloud storage for backups (upload by passing a http-link)

Tags: backup, storage, files, cloud

We have our backups available via direct http and we are serching for a cloud provider with a feature:
We should give a backup http or ftp link to it`s control panel or api and it should upload this file to the storage.

Do you now such providers?
Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick thing... Make sure those backups are encrypted and checksummed. Sending backups over the internet without any protection (which is not provided by HTTP or FTP) is a can of worms you do not wish to open. Beyond that somebody might simply grab all the data you backup you are very vulnerable to transmission errors.

Answer (score 0):

[Iron Mountain](http://ironmountain.com) provides backup uploading via FTP.